# define a predicate solution/3 which is true when its three arguments, all lists, has the third list containing all elements of the first two arguments

Tags: prolog, predicate

```
solution([ ], List, List).
solution([Head|Tail], List,[Head|Result]):-  
solution(Tail, List,Result).
```

expected output

```
| ?- Solution(X,Y,[a,b,c]).

X = [a,b,c]
Y = [] ? ;

X = [a,b]
Y = [c] ? ;

X = [a,c]
Y = [b] ? ;

X = [a]
Y = [b,c] ? ;

X = [b,c]
Y = [a] ? ;

X = [b]
Y = [a,c] ? ;

X = [c]
Y = [a,b] ? ;

X = []
Y = [a,b,c] ? ;
```

actual output

X = []
    Y = [a,b,c] ? ;

```
X = [a]
Y = [b,c] ? ;

X = [a,b]
Y = [c] ? ;

X = [a,b,c]
Y = [] ? ;
```

It is not going through all the possible solutions that can be made from the predicate defined. i am expecting the output to be as shown above containing all the solutions of combining 2 lists together
Any help?

Comment: Why is `x = [c, b, a], Y = []` not a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate is missing some clauses. The first clause says that if the first list is exhausted, then the result is the second list.

The second clause specifies that if the first list is not exhausted, we simply take the first element of that list as a result. This thus means that you basically implemented an [**`append/3`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3).

Based on your sample output, there is however a decision whether to take from the first list, or the second list. We thus should implement a clause like:

```
solution([H1|T1], L2, [H1|R]) :-
    solution(T1, L2, R).
solution(L1, [H1|T2], [H1|R]) :-
    solution(L1, T2, R).
```

If both lists are exhausted, we can return an empty list, so we can define a base-clause like:

```
solution([], [], []).
```

and thus obtain as full solution:

```
solution([], [], []).
solution([H1|T1], L2, [H1|R]) :-
    solution(T1, L2, R).
solution(L1, [H1|T2], [H1|R]) :-
    solution(L1, T2, R).
```

This then gives us:

```
?- solution(X,Y,[a,b,c]).
X = [a, b, c],
Y = [] ;
X = [a, b],
Y = [c] ;
X = [a, c],
Y = [b] ;
X = [a],
Y = [b, c] ;
X = [b, c],
Y = [a] ;
X = [b],
Y = [a, c] ;
X = [c],
Y = [a, b] ;
X = [],
Y = [a, b, c].
```